# Finding the minimum value of $\frac{p}{q-r}$, where $(-1,p)$, $(0,q)$, $(1,r)$ lie on parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$, with certain conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, maxima-minima

> If the vertex of the parabola $$y=ax^2+bx+c \qquad (0<2a<-b)$$is not below the x-axis.  Let there be three points on the parabola: $A(-1,p), B(0,q)$ and $C(1,r)$. Then what is the minimum value of $\dfrac{p}{q-r}$ ?
>
> Hint: the answer is $3$.

My thoughts:

Since the axis of symmetry of the function is $x=-\dfrac{b}{2a}>1$ and $\Delta=b^2-4ac<0$, $\dfrac{p}{q-r}=-\dfrac{a-b+c}{a+b}$,  I thought of solving it by the image of the function. But it seems difficult to find the answer only through the limited conditions.

Comment: Note that $\frac{p}{q-r}=-\frac{a-b+c}{a+b}$.

Comment: Note that your objective function is independent of scaling p, q, r by a common factor, so you can choose $q=1$ as the intercept right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=a(x-x_s)^2+y_s$; we know that $a>0$, $x_s\ge1$ and $y_s\ge0$.  We search for a minimum of
$$\begin{align}
d(a,x_s,y_s)&:=\frac{f(-1)}{f(0)-f(1)}\\
&=\frac{(1+x_s)^2}{2x_s-1}+\frac{y_s}{a(2x_s-1)}\\
&=d(a,x_s,0)+\frac{y_s}{a(2x_s-1)}.
\end{align}$$

First verify that for $y_s=0$ the minimum of
$$d(a,x_s,0)=\frac{(1+x_s)^2}{2x_s-1}$$
is achieved iff $x_s=2$; then $d=3$, it doesn't depend on $a$.

Finally
$$d(a,x_s,y_s)-d(a,x_s,0)=\frac{y_s}{a(2x_s-1)}>0.$$

Comment: Why the minimum of  $d(a,x_s,0)=\frac{(1+x_s)^2}{2x_s-1}$ is achieved iff $x_s=2$ ?

Comment: Just take the derivative in respect to $x_s$; it's $$2\frac{(x-2)(x+1)}{(1-2x)^2}.$$